# force overwrite the copy command ssh?

Tags: linux, command-line, ssh, centos, copy-paste

I'm looking for something like forcing/bypassing overwrite in ssh on copy command??

For Example : If I have a file test1 in /home and in /root

I want to copy the file from root to overwrite on home directory like if I write

## cp test1 /home

cp: overwrite `/home/test1'?

How can we remove this question?
How can we force it not to show this overwrite line ... bypass this to yes bydefault 
I tried -Rf but not working still I'm seeing this....

Anything on this is great help ... 
I check stack overflow and received this answer but didn't get weather it is working or not

yes | cp -R test1 /home

Is there anything wrong on this??

Thanks & Regards

Kishan Giri

Comment: Are you still getting error with `yes | cp -R test1 /home` command?

Comment: `cp -f file /dir` will work **IF** perms on `file` will allow you to write to `/dir`. If your account is not the owner of `file` or `dir` then need a `/dir` with perms 777 and the file must be 666.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use `cp -f test1 /home` command